# Re-queue a Logstash event

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

Is it possible to re-queue a Logstash event to be processed again in a bit of time?

In order to illustrate what I mean, I will explain my use case: I have a custom Logstash filter that extracts the application version from logs at the start of an application, and then appends the correct version to every log event. However in the very beginning, race conditions can occur where an application version has not yet been written to a file, and yet the Logstash filter tries to read in the data anyway (since it it processing log lines concurrently). This results in an application version that is null. In case it matters, Logstash gets its input from Filebeat.

I would like to re-queue these events to be re-processed entirely a couple seconds (or milliseconds) from now, when the application version has been saved to the disk.

However this leads me to a broader question, which is, can you tell a Logstash event to be re-queued, or is there an alternative solution to this scenario?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Process data and append in a new file after that use that file to further process data.

- Logstash Processor - 1 Geat Data Proces Data and append to file.
- Logstash Processor - 2 Get Data From 2nd File and do whatever you
  want to do.

Comment: That seems a bit like a hack to me. I mean I can build my own queue, I was more wondering if a way exists these sort of things are meant to be handled. Besides, this requires two instances of Logstash, and that's something I want to avoid.

Comment: There is nothing like that exists yet or something which I am not aware of

Comment: Or another thing you can use elasticsearch input plugin with the schedule to run every hour or so or what ever time you decide.